# modifying list of class items within a function

Tags: python-3.7

I have a list of class instances. I want to modify the class variables of the list within a function call. in the below simple example, I can't understand why for the first item in the list, the class variable seems to be identical to the second item...

```py
import numpy as np
import cv2

class laneMark():
        winC = np.int32()
        winInd = []

        def __init__(self, winC, winInd):
            self.winC=winC
            self.winInd=winInd

        def update(self, nb, series):
            self.winC=nb
            self.winInd=series

#initialisation of the list with '-1' for winC
memLaneMrk= np.ndarray((2),dtype=laneMark)
memLaneMrk[:] = laneMark(-1,[])

# f1 is meant to update the 2 items (class instance) of the list with new values
def f1(laneMarking):
    laneMarking[0].update(2,[1,2,3])
    laneMarking[1].update(4,[5,6,7])
    return laneMarking

memLaneMrk = f1(memLaneMrk)
print ("winC = %d, winInd =%s" %(memLaneMrk[0].winC,memLaneMrk[0].winInd))
print ("winC = %d, winInd =%s" %(memLaneMrk[1].winC,memLaneMrk[1].winInd))
```

Current output:

```py
winC = 4, winInd =[5, 6, 7]
winC = 4, winInd =[5, 6, 7]
```

Expected output:

```py
winC = 3, winInd =[1, 2, 3]
winC = 4, winInd =[5, 6, 7]
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at `memLaneMrk` on my computer:

`array([<__main__.laneMark object at 0x1170588d0>,
       <__main__.laneMark object at 0x1170588d0>], dtype=object)`

the two items refer to one same object.

Update: replace `memLaneMrk[:] = laneMark(-1,[])` with `memLaneMrk[:] = [laneMark(-1,[]), laneMark(-1,[])]` will solve the problem.

Comment: Thanks a lot XiMin, I understand my mistake. Yes, it fixed the pb!

Comment: @Scoubidouu  Welcome to SO, happy to help you. Can you accept my answer to give me some reputation？Thx.